# Evitar que API deje de ejecutarse tras forzar perdida de conexión a DB

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Cómo se puede evitar errores o más bien que la API deje de ejecutarse cuando fuerzo que la conexión a la base de datos se pierda cuando pongo mi laptop en airplane mode.

Estoy usando Mongo Atlas

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster-tw5lh.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', { 
    dbName: 'databasename', useNewUrlParser: true}).then(() => {
        console.log("Connected to Database");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Not Connected to Database ERROR! ", err);
    });
```

El then y catch solo sirven al iniciar la API.

No existe algo así como el try except de python?

Este es mi endpoint

```
// api-routes.js
router.route('/measures')
    .get(contactController.index)

// contactController.js
Contact = require('./contactModel');

exports.index = function (req, res) {
    Contact.get(function (err, measures) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({
                status: "error",
                message: err,
            });
        }
        res.json({
            status: "success",
            message: "measures retrieved successfully",
            data: measures
        });
    });
};

// contactModel.js
var Measure = module.exports = mongoose.model('measures', measuresSchema);
module.exports.get = function (callback, limit) {
    Measure.find(callback).limit(limit);
}
```

Comment: soy newbie help

Comment: Por que no creas una base de datos en local? Tambien puedes hacer un mock con postman.

Comment: por supuesto que lo hice. Ahora está online en MongoDB Atlas. El punto es cómo evitar posibles problemas de conexión a la base de datos

Comment: Puedes crear un middleware que,  antes de cualquier peticion compruebe el estatus de la BD. Metes un ` try catch` y retornas una peticion que diga que esta offline.

Comment: mmm. Puse un try{} catch(err){} pero no funcionó. El tema es donde debe agregarse. Usandolo aquí no hay ningun cambio. try{ Measure.find(callback).limit(limit)} catch(err){console.log("HolaMundo")}

Answer (score 0):

Debes de ponerlo en tu `app.js` o `index` antes de procesar cualquier petición.

Este es un ejemplo en `express`.

```
app.use((req, resp, next) =>
{
  if (baseDeDatosConectada)
  {
    return res.send(204).json({msj_error: 'La BD esta offline' })
  } else
  { 
    return next()
  }

} )
```

Puedes capturar cualquier error con un middleware. Esto hara que no se rompa el servidor:

```
app.use(function(err, res, req) {
  return res.status(500)send {
    msj: "Hubo un error.",
    err: err
  })
})
```

La conexión solo se crea una vez a la BD mientras inicias el servidor. Son aplicaciones independientes y pueden funcionar sin estar en linea una y otra.

Si capturas bien todos los errores la aplicación no debería detenerse.

Comment: cómo se supone que la condición del IF va antes que la conexión de la base de datos que mostré en el post. Tendrá error

Comment: Actualice la respuesta.